# How do Aperture stacks work in the Photos app?

Tags: macos, photos, aperture, photos.app

What happens when an Aperture stack is imported into photos? It seems that all of the images in the stack get imported as individual images with no relation to one another. Can that possibly be right?

Comment: How are you looking at the Photos in Photos app? Can you choose the view menu and sort by date?

Comment: @bmike: Yes. It's checked and disabled (in a shared album).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know about Photos Version 1.0 (209.52.0):

- Albums you make in Photos are only sortable by date ascending or manually (drag the photos in the order you wish)
- Shared Albums are not sortable - last in on the bottom
- The All Photos album isn't sortable - last in on the bottom (and imports are multi-threaded, so don't expect photos to be arranged in any order like they were on the filesystem when you let the app loose on an import of more than one photo.)
- Burst photos seem to stay grouped (most of the time) and Aperture stacks do not ever stay grouped.

Basically, the rule is you don't even have a sort option enabled and when you do, it's one direction by time so you get one default sort to sometimes enforce in Photos 1.0

Comment: So: Aperture stacks are unstacked and no relationship is preserved?

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the case.  I'm going through all my stacks and unstacking them in Aperture before migrating to prevent having all these duplicates in the albums.  If they would convert stacks to bursts, that would have been awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell:

- All the images are imported.
- The "Stack Pick" gets the keyword "Stack Pick."
- (Very unfortunately…) In all other respects, images that were parts of stacks are indistinguishable from images that are not parts of stacks.

This means it's not possible to automatically find all images that are parts of stacks, but not the stack pick. (To move them to a separate folder, for example.)

**Update** I [wrote a script](https://github.com/ithinkihaveacat/dotfiles/blob/master/applescript/photos-stacks-fixer.applescript) to help "fix" this problem: you can use it to move the non picks into a separate album, export them to a separate directory, and then delete them from Photos.

Comment: Yes, that's how it seems. Pretty incredible!